# facebook load xd_proxy.php while scrolling

Tags: facebook, loading

Hi anyone have idea what's going on with the iframe apps on facebook keep loading the xd_proxy.php? I haven't notice it's a new or existing issue because my apps screen is fix, today, when I change some code,I scrolling the screen with my mouse, and discover that the xd_proxy is loading while scrolling(no matter use mouse wheel, kb arrow, scroll bar..), I search some posts in the google and stack overflow, but with no luck, none of them can solve it, I've try add the channelurl, rearrange the javascript...etc, but no luck, please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also having this problem, luckily it looks to be Facebook's fault rather than ours, as I am seeing it on all apps I've seen that use the new Facebook Javascript API, most notably, CityVille.

Comment: hope the facebook team will fix it soon, it really annoying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logged as a bug in Facebook's bug tracker now.  Best way to get it fixed is to vote for it!

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16176

Answer (score 1):

Facebook fixed a bug we have been waiting on in their JS SDK this week so we were planning on switching from the old JS SDK to the new but during final testing came across this as well. Looks like window location is being reported back.

Anyone know if this is new and what exactly it is used for? Can it be disabled? Wonder what this would do to performance across different environments.

Answer (score 1):

This starts happening after FB.init in window.fbAsyncInit is called with de JS SDK. It is passing height and width of the client and scroll as parameters with type canvasPage.update. It might, but I do not know, have something to do with a bug earlier this year when apps in iframes weren't resizing, something like a work around.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed this today as well, and initially thought it was due to FB.Canvas.setAutoResize() being called surreptitiously, but nope, it seems like scroll has been bound to this update.